# PowerShell Invoke-Webrequest not compatible with site? - Part 2

Tags: powershell

Regarding my previous question, "PowerShell Invoke-Webrequest not compatible with site?" that was successfully answered by Tessellating Heckler, I have one further question. If I want to proceed to the next step which is to simply select the "Delivery" option, Fiddler shows a destination URL of:

"https://order.swisschalet.com/order/order/setup/how/save?preventCache=1476633843277"

In PowerShell, how can I obtain and store the "preventCache" number that seems to be randomly generated? If I try to post to just "https://order.swisschalet.com/order/order/setup/how/save" it doesn't work. Also, and interestingly, this is not one of the available "Actions" that one sees when you type $a.forms.action (again, see the previous solution). If I try the action starting with "order.swisschalet.com/order/order/setup/complete"

the response seems to be ok but no actual progress can be found in the response body.

FYI: When doing this in a browser and then looking at the JSON response in Fiddler one can see a 'message=Successfully set service mode'. I can never get this no matter what I do through PowerShell.

I suppose like the last time the answer to this is relatively simple and I'm missing it again, but I cannot proceed past this point. If I can then I believe everything else will make sense going forward.

Thank you for any help as this has been driving me crazy!

Original code:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 # This is required so that HTTPS requests won't fail with Invoke-WebRequest
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://order.swisschalet.com -SessionVariable sc
$form = @{
    delegate='login'
    id='null'
    mode='save'
    target='#form-login'
    email='email@example.com'
    password='password'
}
$a = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://order.swisschalet.com/order/auth/index" -WebSession $sc -Method POST -Body $form
```

Comment: It sounds like you just need to grab the `preventCache` field from the response. It would be helpful to see the response body from your original request. I know this question is related to a previous question that you had but, in general, it is best if you can write your questions in such a way that they stand on their own. It would provide better value to anybody that happens to land on this page from a web search and I think you will find that your question gets more/better attention.

Comment: Hi Jason, you are right and I will do that in the future. I just tried adding the code in the comment section and it didn't turn out right so I deleted it. With regards to a 'preventCache' field, it would be great if I could find one. I've checked all the raw content and the only reference to a cache is no-cache, so I am not sure where it is coming from.

Comment: Can you take your response from Fiddler (headers and all) and update your question to include the response?  Or the response in PowerShell if you have that.

Comment: I'm not sure what to try to show you from Fiddler. As for PowerShell, the raw response is pretty long. Is there a way to attach a text file?

Comment: The fastest way would be to just create a free account at https://order.swisschalet.com (click the 'Login / Register' button). Once you are done then you can exit the browser, launch a PowerShell console and then copy the above code and substitute the email and password and then you will have all the results in $a

Comment: Sorry, for clarity, the 'preventCache' in the URI comes from when you manually go to the site and click 'Delivery'. This can be seen in Fiddler, but in PowerShell I never get any 'preventCache' value in $a, and no matter what URI I then try to post to.